# What version of SQL Server can I use on Sitecore 9

Tags: sql-database

I was wondering what version of SQL Server is best used (or allowed to be used) with Sitecore 9: SQL Web or Standard?

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016

I've been looking through some documentation and can't seem to find the answer I am looking for.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can check the section **Database Server** from the Compatibility table provided by Sitecore: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will say both are supported if Sitecore didn't mention on documentation.

They are close, but not quite the same. The primary difference is the licensing.

The other differences are

1. Mirroring (web can only serve as a witness)
2. Publishing (web can only subscribe)
3. Performance (web does not come    with SQL Profiler)

[image]

On a production environment I will install Enterprise version.

Comment: I agree Vlad, from what I can find that seems the most logical answer. Thx

Answer (score 4):

Sitecore 9.0 supports the following database servers:

- Microsoft SQL Server 2016 SP1: This version supports the XM databases
  and is the required and only supported version for the Experience
  Database (xDB).
- Microsoft SQL Server 2014 SP2: This version only supports XM
  databases and does not support the Experience Database (xDB).

Edition of MS SQL Server depends only on your solution architecture requirements.

> **Important:** Sitecore XP 9.0 rev. 171002 does not currently support
>   MongoDB or Oracle databases for the Experience Database (xDB). Support
>   will be added in future versions of Sitecore.
>
> **Note:** You can also use Windows authentication to connect to the SQL server.

Comment: Yes, I found that information myself too. However, the question is if this can be the "Web" or "Standard" edition...

Comment: See this question:https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8590/sitecore-9-installation-error

Comment: Edition of MS SQL Server depends only on your solution architecture requirements.