# Provisioning to Azure failure on deploying CM

Tags: azure, paas, arm-template

I am trying to setup a new Sitecore 9.2 instance on PAAS using ARM templates. I used these templates a few months ago on the same subscription to setup our development environment and that worked fine. Now I'm trying to provision the same setup in a different resource group and getting this error:

```
{
    "status": "failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
        "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'failed'.",
        "details": [
            {
                "code": "Failed",
                "message": "Package deployment failed\r\nAppGallery Deploy Failed: 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentDetailedClientServerException: Could not deploy package.\r\nUnable to connect to master or target server 'fxxxx-acc-920-core-db'. You must have a user with the same password in master or target server 'fxxxx-acc-920-core-db'.\r\n  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD. ---&gt; Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServicesException: Could not deploy package. ---&gt; Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.DeploymentFailedException: Unable to connect to master or target server 'fxxxx-acc-920-core-db'. You must have a user with the same password in master or target server 'fxxxx-acc-920-core-db'.\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeploymentEndpointServer.OnInit(ErrorManager errors, String targetDBName)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeployment..ctor(SqlDeploymentConstructor constructor)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeploymentConstructor.ConstructServiceImplementation()\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.CreatePackageToDatabaseDeployment(SqlConnectionFactory connectionFactory, IPackageSource packageSource, String targetDatabaseName, DacDeployOptions options, ErrorManager errorManager)\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass3.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass5.&lt;CreatePlanInitializationOperation&gt;b__1()\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Dac.OperationLogger.Capture(Action action)\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass3.&lt;CreatePlanInitializationOperation&gt;b__0(Object operation, CancellationToken token)\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Operation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.ReportMessageOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.OperationExtension.CompositeOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.OperationExtension.CompositeOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.OperationExtension.Execute(IOperation operation, DacLoggingContext loggingContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.InternalDeploy(IPackageSource packageSource, Boolean isDacpac, String targetDatabaseName, DacDeployOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken, DacLoggingContext loggingContext, Action`3 reportPlanOperation, Boolean executePlan)\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.Deploy(DacPackage package, String targetDatabaseName, Boolean upgradeExisting, DacDeployOptions options, Nullable`1 cancellationToken)\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.SqlReflectionHelper.ExecuteFunction(Object targetObject, String methodName, Object[] argArray)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DacServices.ProcessDacpac(Stream packageStream, DacPacAction action)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.SqlDacPacProvider.Add(DeploymentObject source, Boolean whatIf)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.Add(DeploymentObject source, DeploymentSyncContext syncContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.HandleAdd(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildren(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.ProcessSync(DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable, Nullable`1 syncPassId, String syncSessionId)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.Deploy(String deploymentSite, String siteSlotId, Boolean doNotDelete)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&lt;DownloadAndDeployPackage&gt;d__24.MoveNext()'"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Long error short: `Unable to connect to master or target server 'fxxxx-acc-920-core-db'. You must have a user with the same password in master or target server 'fxxxx-acc-920-core-db'`

I did find this question [You must have a user with the same password in master or target server](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/8590/237) which mentions the same error but that is for a local install. I can't seem to find any relevant solution for Azure PAAS :(

Anyone an idea?

Comment: I would recommend running Sitecore Experience Cloud to Template to install new Instance in Azure PaaS especially for Scaled Environment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem is from a [breaking change by Microsoft](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-SQL-Database/General-availability-Database-compatibility-level-150-in-Azure/ba-p/1003458) where they changed the default compatibility level to 150. The Sitecore cloud team was on it straight away [and have released a fix](https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates/commit/b37ae9e57bce566de6b8ef127722ebad17c76521) which is to deploy a small package to set the compatibility level on newly created Azure SQL databases.