# Clean install on Azure SQL Managed instance

Tags: xconnect, azure, paas, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to install `Sitecore 9.2 vanilla` on `Azure with SQL Managed Instance` but I am getting the following error

```
{
"status": "failed",
"error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'failed'.",
    "details": [
        {
            "code": "Failed",
            "message": ".Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 5008, Level 16, State 14, Line 5 This ALTER DATABASE statement is not supported. Correct the syntax and execute the statement again.\r\n.Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 5008, Level 16, State 14, Line 5 This ALTER DATABASE statement is not supported. Correct the syntax and execute the statement again.\r\nScript execution error.  The executed script:\r\nIF EXISTS (SELECT 1\r\n           FROM   [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases]\r\n           WHERE  [name] = N'$(DatabaseName)')\r\n    BEGIN\r\n        ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]\r\n            SET ANSI_NULLS ON,\r\n                ANSI_PADDING ON,\r\n                ANSI_WARNINGS ON,\r\n                ARITHABORT ON,\r\n                CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON,\r\n                QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON,\r\n                ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT ON,\r\n                CURSOR_DEFAULT LOCAL,\r\n                RECOVERY SIMPLE \r\n            WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;\r\n    END\r\n\r\n\r\nScript execution error.  The executed script:\r\nIF EXISTS (SELECT 1\r\n           FROM   [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases]\r\n           WHERE  [name] = N'$(DatabaseName)')\r\n    BEGIN\r\n        ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]\r\n            SET ANSI_NULLS ON,\r\n                ANSI_PADDING ON,\r\n                ANSI_WARNINGS ON,\r\n                ARITHABORT ON,\r\n                CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON,\r\n                QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON,\r\n                ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT ON,\r\n                CURSOR_DEFAULT LOCAL,\r\n                RECOVERY SIMPLE \r\n            WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;\r\n    END\r\n\r\n\r\n.Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 ALTER DATABASE statement failed.\r\n.Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 ALTER DATABASE statement failed.\r\nScript execution error.  The executed script:\r\nIF EXISTS (SELECT 1\r\n           FROM   [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases]\r\n           WHERE  [name] = N'$(DatabaseName)')\r\n    BEGIN\r\n        ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]\r\n            SET ANSI_NULLS ON,\r\n                ANSI_PADDING ON,\r\n                ANSI_WARNINGS ON,\r\n                ARITHABORT ON,\r\n                CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON,\r\n                QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON,\r\n                ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT ON,\r\n                CURSOR_DEFAULT LOCAL,\r\n                RECOVERY SIMPLE \r\n            WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;\r\n    END\r\n\r\n\r\nScript execution error.  The executed script:\r\nIF EXISTS (SELECT 1\r\n           FROM   [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases]\r\n           WHERE  [name] = N'$(DatabaseName)')\r\n    BEGIN\r\n        ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]\r\n            SET ANSI_NULLS ON,\r\n                ANSI_PADDING ON,\r\n                ANSI_WARNINGS ON,\r\n                ARITHABORT ON,\r\n                CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON,\r\n                QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON,\r\n                ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT ON,\r\n                CURSOR_DEFAULT LOCAL,\r\n                RECOVERY SIMPLE \r\n            WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;\r\n    END\r\n\r\n\r\nPackage deployment failed\r\nAppGallery Deploy Failed: 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentDetailedClientServerException: Could not deploy package.\r\nWarning SQL0: A project which specifies SQL Server 2016 as the target platform may experience compatibility issues with SQL Server 2014.\r\nWarning SQL72030: The project and target databases have different collation settings. Deployment errors might occur.\r\nError SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 5008, Level 16, State 14, Line 5 This ALTER DATABASE statement is not supported. Correct the syntax and execute the statement again.\r\nError SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:\r\nIF EXISTS (SELECT 1\r\n           FROM   [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases]\r\n           WHERE  [name] = N'$(DatabaseName)')\r\n    BEGIN\r\n        ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]\r\n            SET ANSI_NULLS ON,\r\n                ANSI_PADDING ON,\r\n                ANSI_WARNINGS ON,\r\n                ARITHABORT ON,\r\n                CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON,\r\n                QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON,\r\n                ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT ON,\r\n                CURSOR_DEFAULT LOCAL,\r\n                RECOVERY SIMPLE \r\n            WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;\r\n    END\r\n\r\n\r\nError SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 ALTER DATABASE statement failed.\r\nError SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:\r\nIF EXISTS (SELECT 1\r\n           FROM   [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases]\r\n           WHERE  [name] = N'$(DatabaseName)')\r\n    BEGIN\r\n        ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]\r\n            SET ANSI_NULLS ON,\r\n                ANSI_PADDING ON,\r\n                ANSI_WARNINGS ON,\r\n                ARITHABORT ON,\r\n                CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON,\r\n                QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON,\r\n                ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT ON,\r\n                CURSOR_DEFAULT LOCAL,\r\n                RECOVERY SIMPLE \r\n            WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;\r\n    END\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD. ---&amp;amp;amp;amp;gt; Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServicesException: Could not deploy package.\r\nWarning SQL0: A project which specifies SQL Server 2016 as the target platform may experience compatibility issues with SQL Server 2014.\r\nWarning SQL72030: The project and target databases have different collation settings. Deployment errors might occur.\r\nError SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 5008, Level 16, State 14, Line 5 This ALTER DATABASE statement is not supported. Correct the syntax and execute the statement again.\r\nError SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:\r\nIF EXISTS (SELECT 1\r\n           FROM   [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases]\r\n           WHERE  [name] = N'$(DatabaseName)')\r\n    BEGIN\r\n        ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]\r\n            SET ANSI_NULLS ON,\r\n                ANSI_PADDING ON,\r\n                ANSI_WARNINGS ON,\r\n                ARITHABORT ON,\r\n                CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON,\r\n                QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON,\r\n                ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT ON,\r\n                CURSOR_DEFAULT LOCAL,\r\n                RECOVERY SIMPLE \r\n            WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;\r\n    END\r\n\r\n\r\nError SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 ALTER DATABASE statement failed.\r\nError SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:\r\nIF EXISTS (SELECT 1\r\n           FROM   [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases]\r\n           WHERE  [name] = N'$(DatabaseName)')\r\n    BEGIN\r\n        ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]\r\n            SET ANSI_NULLS ON,\r\n                ANSI_PADDING ON,\r\n                ANSI_WARNINGS ON,\r\n                ARITHABORT ON,\r\n                CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON,\r\n                QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON,\r\n                ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT ON,\r\n                CURSOR_DEFAULT LOCAL,\r\n                RECOVERY SIMPLE \r\n            WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;\r\n    END\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.ThrowIfErrorManagerHasErrors()\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.&amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;&amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;c__DisplayClass14.&amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;&amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;c__DisplayClass16.&amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;CreatePlanExecutionOperation&amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;b__13()\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Dac.OperationLogger.Capture(Action action)\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.&amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;&amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;c__DisplayClass14.&amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;CreatePlanExecutionOperation&amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;b__12(Object operation, CancellationToken token)\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Operation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.ReportMessageOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.OperationExtension.Execute(IOperation operation, DacLoggingContext loggingContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.InternalDeploy(IPackageSource packageSource, Boolean isDacpac, String targetDatabaseName, DacDeployOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken, DacLoggingContext loggingContext, Action`3 reportPlanOperation, Boolean executePlan)\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.Deploy(DacPackage package, String targetDatabaseName, Boolean upgradeExisting, DacDeployOptions options, Nullable`1 cancellationToken)\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.SqlReflectionHelper.ExecuteFunction(Object targetObject, String methodName, Object[] argArray)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DacServices.ProcessDacpac(Stream packageStream, DacPacAction action)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.SqlDacPacProvider.Add(DeploymentObject source, Boolean whatIf)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.Add(DeploymentObject source, DeploymentSyncContext syncContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.HandleAdd(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildren(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.ProcessSync(DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable, Nullable`1 syncPassId, String syncSessionId)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.Deploy(String deploymentSite, String siteSlotId, Boolean doNotDelete)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;DownloadAndDeployPackage&amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;d__24.MoveNext()"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

However, I was able to deploy previously using `SQL PaaS`.

Is it because Sitecore does not support Azure SQL Managed Instance or something is changed recently?

I check the collation which is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` and `COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL` is 150.

I am using Sitecore Azure Toolkit for installation with some customisation to reference the correct resourceId for managed instance.

Any help, please.

Thanks

Comment: Check this out: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/23527/provisioning-to-azure-failure-on-deploying-cm/23541?stw=2#23541

Comment: I tried to change compatibility level to 130 and it's still the same issue

Comment: Please add more detail of how you are deploying. You've tagged SIF and PaaS which are not compatible with each other. You should be using Sitecore Azure Toolkit.

Comment: @MarkGibbons you are correct, I am using the Sitecore Azure Toolkit and further customization was required for SQL MI to reference correct resourceId

Comment: Assuming changing the compatibility level still doesn't work, then probably sitecore support is a good next step.

Comment: Yeah I changed the compatibility level and still no luck

Comment: I have raised the support ticket and received the response. Sitecore doesn't officially support Azure SQL Managed Instance and it has not been tested yet. Thus, they have registered a feature request for the product so that it can be considered for future implementation. The public reference number for the feature request is 311965.